# Declaring a pointer in a loop

Tags: objective-c

everyone. My "engrish" is not very good but I hope you will understand my problem.

Let's say I have a code like this

```
-(id) init
{
    if ( self = [super init] )
    {
        deck = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:52];
        Card *newCard = [[Card alloc] init];

        for ( int suit = 0; suit < 4; suit++ )
            for ( int rank = 0; rank < 13; rank++ )
            {
                newCard.suit = suit;
                newCard.rank = rank;
                [deck addObject:newCard];
            }
        [newCard release];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I'm feeling like I have a mistake in the aforementioned code. I want to create 52 different objects in nested loops and add every object in array. But I suspect that I'll have 52 same objects and in array will be 52 pointers that point to the same address, right?

What happens if I make like this.

```
-(id) init
{
    if ( self = [super init] )
    {
        deck = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:52];

        for ( int suit = 0; suit < 4; suit++ )
            for ( int rank = 0; rank < 13; rank++ )
            {
                Card *newCard = [[Card alloc] init]; // I guess every time newCard
                newCard.suit = suit;                 // created, it will point to 
                newCard.rank = rank;                 // another chunk of memory,
                [deck addObject:newCard];            // right?
                [newCard release] // Should I release newCard every time?
            }
    }
    return self;
}
```

So which way I can create 52 different cards?
Thank you. If you need more explanations, ask me.

Comment: Did you try running it and using NSLog to print out the results of deck? I.e. `NSLog("%@", deck);`. - you are correct, though

Comment: If you are not using ARC, then yes - you need to release it.

Comment: Please use ARC ;) you cannot do it better.

Comment: I can't use ARC :( My lead programmer says that ARC is good but not all times. So I have to know everything about memory management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question: Your second code sniplet produces 52 individual objects which you add to the array. 
The first sniplet, as you already suggested yourself, produces just one object which you add to the array. As it is one object only all the members of the array will carry the same values for `.suit` and `.rank`.

Als suggested already, when you nslog the objects then you see at least their address in memory. When the address is identical then it is the identical object.

Second question: 
Yes, you should release it unless you use ARC. `addObject` will automatically retain each added object and release it upon removal from the array. So be careful when you fetch the object from the array later and intend to use it further. Then you may have to retain it again.

Alternative to your -correct- code you can autorelease the object using:

```
        Card *newCard = [[[Card alloc] init] autorelease]; // I guess every time newCard
        newCard.suit = suit;                 // created, it will point to 
        newCard.rank = rank;                 // another chunk of memory,
        [deck addObject:newCard];            // right?
        //[newCard release]; // not required, autoreleased
```

(However, a semicolon is missing following the release statement. )

Comment: I don't quite understand: what happens to a pointer (let's say newCard)? We create a pointer, then we send release message to an object it points to, then in next iteration of the loop we create a pointer with the same name? Then what happens to the previous pointer?

Comment: Well, you can declare your pointer within this if and loop or without. In some cases, where switch/case is involved for instance, you have to actually create the pointer out of the switch block. Within the (double) loop you allocate the object. By allocating it it is automatically retained. Alloc returnes a retained object. So does init. Without ARC the memory allocated will not be released until the retain count is 0, meaning for each alloc or retain there was a release (or an autorelease takes effect). Without ARC the memory even keesp allocated when (continued next comment...)

Comment: ... nothing actually points to the object. That is what we call a memory leak. So in your case you create a new object on every iteration of the loop. It is retained by alloc and retained by addObject. Then it is released. Meaning its retain count is 1 and the object keeps alive. That is until it is removed from the array.

Comment: Academic answer: At the end of each iteration of the loop the pointer gets deallocated (well, it is on the stack anyway) and on the beginning of each iteration it is created (On the stack which happens to be at the same point in memory. But it does not have to.) And yes, it gets the same name on each iteration.